# What is the equivalent of "cp --verbose" on windows for copy?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I 'm using the command `copy` in a build script to export *apk* files in a specific folder on the network and rename it by adding the release number as a suffix.

I tried giving the option `-v` but I'm getting the  following error.

```
The system cannot find the file specified
```

if I use the command `cp` I get :

```
'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Copy's /V is "Verify" not Verbose.   What's the actual command you're trying to use when `Copy` with `-v` gives you that error?   Are you remembering to delimit file paths that have spaces in them?  If you don't use `-v` does it work as expected?  Does the file you're trying to copy actually exist?

Answer (score 9):

Try `xcopy` instead.  Perhaps something like:

`xcopy /F "C:\My Folder\file.txt" D:\`

From `xcopy /?`:

> /F - Displays full source and destination file names while copying.

Comment: I am amazed at how simmilar out answers are not only on technicals but format as well.

Comment: @FrankThomas, true. However techie [typed *slightly* faster](http://superuser.com/posts/688055/timeline#rev-6880612013-12-13-05-57).

Answer (score 7):

try `xcopy /f <source> <dest>`

from the usage summary:

> /F           Displays full source and destination file names while
>   copying.

can't get too much more verbose than that on a copy operation.

Comment: I was exactly looking to output the source and destination filenames, but it would be cool if I coud avoid displaying the entire file because it's a zipped package.

Answer (score 3):

For a different answer... try [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).

[xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) has become deprecated (i.e. there are better and more supported tools) as of Windows Vista and up.

```
ROBOCOPY Source_folder Destination_folder /V
```

Where `/V` means:

```
/V : Produce Verbose output log, showing skipped files.
```

robocopy allows for more that that, as it can copy permissions, specific files and attributes and can even generate logs.

Comment: Does it work for a specific source file and destination file because I have to rename the file to suffix the version number by the way ?

Comment: I would assume so (see the embedded link for sample usage) but I rarely use Windows 7.

Comment: Indeed as an optional third argument you can specify a list of files using wildcard (eg ```ROBOCOPY C:\myProject\build\ C:\myProject\release\ *.apk```. Bu I didn't find a way to rename the files in batch

Comment: You didn't mention anything about renaming in your question. However, you could do that with a FOR loop and/or the [REN](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) command.

Comment: You are right. My bad I thought I should edit my question to precise it but I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

I use Robocopy for my batch scripts, but if you're looking for any Windows command, then you can always go for powershell:
copy-item Source Destination -verbose