# Alternative of linux cp --update for Windows

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, copy

On Linux, there is a bash command to copy files, and if the file is already in the destination, to take the newer one based on its timestamp.

```
cp -u source destination
```

The description of this option is:

> -u, --update - Copy only when the source file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing.

Is there such a command for Windows Command Prompt as well? Or can I achieve the same result via other relatively simple means (for free)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the equivalent of "cp --verbose" on windows for copy?](https://superuser.com/questions/688055/what-is-the-equivalent-of-cp-verbose-on-windows-for-copy)

Comment: @Madhubala Well, it does point out `xcopy` and `robocopy`, but it concerns a completely different functionality, so no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) with the `/XO` flag to exclude copying older files.

If you're copying to another machine then you may also wish to use `/FFT` which introduces a tolerance of ± 2 seconds.